# Hash that only lasts a day for a given user

Tags: security, web, cryptography

would this method of generating and checking a hash allow one to create secure user-specific hashes that would only last for a single day?

generate_token: sha(salt + day_of_year + user)

check_token: sha(salt + day_of_year + user) == get['token']

The idea here would be to create an instant-login token that could only last for a single day.  It could be sent by email to individual users.

Comment: What happens when a user logs in at 11:59 PM?

Comment: The day is defined as ending at midnight sharp.  and this is actually the way the site works-- the user must checkin before midnight.  but the reasons for this are not the focus of the question-- just whether  it would work

Comment: Then yes, that *could* work, though you'd need to use a fixed-width date format (e.g. `001, 002, ..., 365` rather than `1, 2, ..., 365`) to avoid security issues due to usernames starting with numbers.

Comment: ah, a clever point!  the answer goes to you sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to calculate an expiry timestamp (current time + 86400 seconds, for instance), and then store that timestamp in the database while also including it in the hash:

```
user | expiry | hash
-----+--------+--------------------------
...  | 123456 | sha(salt + 123456 + user)
```

Then when checking, you see if (a) the hash exists, and (b) it matches the user, and (c) the expiry timestamp hasn't already passed.

This gives you hashes that will always last a day from when they are issued, rather than just lasting until whenever the next day starts.

It also lets you easily prune out expired hashes from your database if you so desire, to keep the number of rows smaller.